# .htaccess Redirect is ignoring several parts of the URL

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/shop/childrens-shinnerz-by-size/extra-small
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/all-extra-small-5-7-yrs
```

with that way

```
Redirect 301 /shop/childrens-shinnerz-by-size/extra-small /sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/all-extra-small-5-7-yrs
```

But it is redirecting on wrong url

```
http://www.example.com/sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/extra-small
```

So parts `all-` and `-5-7-yrs`are ignored.

How can I redirect to the correct URL?

Comment: Try wrapping /sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/all-extra-small-5-7-yrs in quotes?

Comment: No - I got same result with quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use this , it should work:

```
     RedirectMatch 301 http://www.example.com/shop/childrens-shinnerz-by-size/extra-small(.*) http://www.example.com/sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/all-extra-small-5-7-yrs/$1
```

Source: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .htaccess file in the root of your site,

```
  RewriteRule ^shop/childrens-shinnerz-by-size/extra-small(.*)$ http://www.example.com/sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/all-extra-small-5-7-yrs/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/childrens-shinnerz-by-size/extra-small$ /sports-goods/childrens-shinnerz/all-extra-small-5-7-yrs
```

this is working as I wanted

Answer (score -1):

i have tested it on my server and it works fine 
http://www.familybmi.com/shop/childrens-shinnerz-by-size/extra-small 
maybe there's something wrong with your apache try to test something else like

```
Redirect 301 /retiredpage.html http://www.example.com/newpage.html
```

and play a little with that if you don't get the desired results to it means you need maybe to update your apache

Comment: I mentioned it is not working when numbers and keyword `all` in url!

Comment: if there's any rules in the .htaccess file before this one try comment all and just test it maybe there's a rule before it make it behaves this way